# Does "ds" have any statistical meaning?

Tags: case-control-study

I was reading a research paper and was wondering if "ds= .56 to .63" was a quantitative means of measuring the study, or if it was related to referencing? [image]

Comment: Please provide the reference. Without context, this could be anything including a typo.

Answer (score 3):

A Google search suggests https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5353b838e4b0e68461b517cf/t/5cda5ada6e9a7f5573458d7e/1557813983729/beyond+willpower.pdf near the start of page 108:  Duckworth AL, Milkman KL, Laibson D. 2018. Beyond willpower: strategies for reducing failures of self-
control. Psychol. Sci. Public Interest 19:102–29

It looks as if $d$s is the plural of $d$, which is earlier described as *mean differences*, presumably between treatment and control.  It may be [Cohen's $d$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen%27s_d) as a measure of effect size.